# Golden Ape Peculiarity

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language

In the wild he reigns, a colossal beast,

From Skull Island, his power unleashed.

Climbing skyscrapers, a towering sight,

This mighty ape, a legendary might.

---

What is very similar between the ape from the riddle and gold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ape from the riddle

> is [King Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Kong) ([Skull Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull_Island_(King_Kong)), [climbing skyscrapers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qkahQVFzMI))

*What is very common between the ape from the riddle and gold?*

> In English the commonality is the letters GO. Since there is the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag, we can look at other languages, and in Ainu, a language from Japan, [kongane](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%8D#Ainu) means gold. In Japanese, "gold" can be expressed by 金 with Romanized kun'yomi "kugane"/"kogane" or on'yomi "kin". It can also be expressed 黄金, Romanized "ogon", "kokin", "kugane", "kogane", all of which have several letters in common with King Kong.

Comment: Almost there! This has to do with *Japanese*.

Comment: Alright, I'll take this answer, but the very very very similar thing is that rot13(ba'lbzv ernqvat sbe 金 vf xva, xba be tba. Vs jr gnxr xva naq xba ernqvatf gbtrgure vg fbhaqf nyzbfg yvxr Xvat Xbat) :D